# why does a function has different reaction (omitting/adding empty parentheses) when used as an argument to a PyQt button.click.connection method?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using the following code as reference

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton('Hello World')

def on_button_clicked():
    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText('BOO')
    alert.exec()

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec()
```

and while messing around with it, I found that passing `on_button_clicked():` instead of `on_button_clicked:` as the argument on the `button.clicked.connect()`, the app will immediately display the alert instead of awaiting for user to click the button. I am not entirely sure why the difference in parentheses does this, and how I can figure out when to use empty parentheses or not.

explanations are much appreciated.

Comment: With parentheses "on_button_clicked" is called immediately and its return value "None" is the argument for "connect". Without parentheses the function object itself is the argument.

Comment: is the value "None" causing the slot to disregard the signal criteria?

Comment: You don't give a slot to the signal if you use parentheses, only a `None`.

Comment: PyQt5 Docs: [Support for Signals and Slots](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

Comment: @babipichard when functions are executed and arguments of a function are other executed functions, the order is the same as in math: you first resolve what's inside the inner-most parentheses. In your code, if you add parentheses to `on_button_clicked`, it will be immediately executed, so the function will be called and the messagebox will be shown; `exec()` is blocking (until the messagebox is closed), so `button.clicked.connect` is still "waiting" for the returned value of the above function; when the messagebox is closed, `exec()` returns, and `on_button_clicked` returns as well with `None`

Comment: @babipichard with the parentheses, `button.clicked.connect` will use the *returned* value of `on_button_clicked()` (which is `None`, as no `return` statement implies `return None`; the result then will be the same as `button.clicked.connect(None)`, which will throw a `TypeError` exception and will crash the program since `connect` *always* expects a reference to a function.

Comment: got it, thank you everyone for the clarity.